# How can I preserve current SPA route upon page refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an app nearly up and running. I've configured all the state with context API, created all the backend routes and the frontend routes. The data is fetched from the API no problems. Login routes the user to the right destination and so does logging out.

However, when I refresh a page on any given page, the route follows my private route. Here's the code for it as it's a separate component:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isAuthenticated } = authContext;

  return (
    <Route { ...rest } render={props => !isAuthenticated ? (
        <Redirect to='/login' />
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )} 
    />
  )
}
```

My routes on the front end are as follows:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Main} />
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/events' component={EventsPage} />
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/keywords' component={Keywords}/>
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/register' component={Register} />
</Switch>
```

When the user is authenticated and in events, for example, they can see the content. When they refresh, the route goes back to the Login page (as it should) and then re-directs the user back to the main page, at '/' (as it should).

However, I want the page to stay on `Events` when it refreshes.

I've read about having routes configured correctly on both the backend as well as the front end but not sure how to implement as everything works fine other than this.

Comment: `When they refresh, the route goes back to the Login page (as it should)` why?

Comment: I mainly did this to make sure that any unauthenticated user can only see the Login page of the app. However, when a user is logged in and visits the Login page, it automatically redirects them to the main dashboard. When the page is refreshed, this last functionality is what the user experiences (takes them to the Login page, then redirects to dashboard). I just don't know how to keep them on the page where they refreshed!

Answer (score 0):

My guess without seeing the rest of your code would be that you are storing the information that decides whether or not a user is authenticated in state that resets on refresh rather than something that persists on reload like session storage, local storage or cookie.

Comment: In my Auth state with the Context API, a JWT token is generated and saved in local storage, so the user state is maintained until the user logs out. I read that this maintains the state for the user, but didn't really find an answer that helps to keep the page the user is on the same after a refresh...Which is where I think my understanding falters a bit - is there a wider user state and then a state for the page that the user is on?

Comment: You omitted that code so that was only a guess. If you are saving to and reading from local storage correctly it shouldn't log out on refresh. You may want to debug that code.