# My protected Route is not working Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do a protected Route but its not working!

One of the warnings that appeared was that i can't use Route render and Route children in the same route. I did that and also didn't work.

If my auth is false i should be redirected to path='/'. Instead, when i reload my page with the path of 
'/loginT' it just does that reloads and stays in that path.

App.js

```
function App() {

 const auth = React.useState(false);
 const toxi = Cookies.get('toxi');
 const ajudante = Cookies.get('ajudante');
 console.log(toxi);
 console.log(ajudante);


 return (

<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar authToxi={toxi} authAjudante={ajudante} />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/logins' component={LogIns} />
      <Route path='/loginAjudante' component={LogInAjudante} />
      <ProtectedRoute path='/loginT' auth={auth} >
        <LogInToxi />
      </ProtectedRoute>
      <Route path='/signupToxi' component={SignUpViciado} />
      <Route path='/signupAjudante' component={SignUpAjudante} />
      <Route exact component={PageNotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>

  );

}
```

ProtectedRoute.js

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({auth, Component: Component, ...rest }) => {
return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={
            props => auth ? 
            (<Component {...props} />)
            :(<Redirect to={{pathname:"/"}}/>)
        }
    />
)
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529790/react-preserve-current-spa-route-upon-page-refresh

Comment: I think i have tried a similar thing. I will try again

Answer (score 1):

For your ProtectedRouteJs, you accept a component attribute, you should code like this

```
<ProtectedRoute path='/loginT' auth={auth} component={LogInToxi} />

//Change your ProtectedRoute.js to
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props}/>
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}}/>}/>
    );
}

// remember change to something like this "component: Component", not "Component: Component"
```

Comment: it worked too well. when my state is true it also redirects to path='/'